# How to add multiple generic type constraints for a type parameter in VS 2010 UML Class Diagram parameterized type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml, class-diagram

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public class Foo<T>
        where T : IFoo, IFoo2
    {
        public Foo(T fooThing)
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Name {get;}
    }

    public interface IFoo2
    {
        string Name2 {get;}
    }
}
```

The Template Parameter Collection Editor in VS 2010 UML class diagram designer, doesn't seem to allow you add multiple constraints to a single generic type parameter.

(image was rejected because I don't have enough "reputation" points )

Am I missing something? Basically, how do I model in VS 2010 UML Class Designer, multiple type parameter constraints like that in the code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct - VS can't show that.  The UI only lets you pick one constraining type.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I figured would be the answer.